# what is the equivalent of err := db.Model(&users).Where("id in (?)", pg.In(ids)).Select() in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to switch a go backend project from postgres to mongodb, the final missing piece that I couldn't fix is this

```
err := db.Model(&users).Where("id in (?)", pg.In(ids)).Select()
```

Could anyone help me with its equivalent in mongodb

This is the code I want to change

```
const userloaderKey = "userloader"

func DataloaderMiddleware(db *pg.DB, next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        userloader := UserLoader{
            maxBatch: 100,
            wait:     1 * time.Millisecond,
            fetch: func(ids []string) ([]*models.User, []error) {
                var users []*models.User

                err := db.Model(&users).Where("id in (?)", pg.In(ids)).Select()

                if err != nil {
                    return nil, []error{err}
                }

                u := make(map[string]*models.User, len(users))

                for _, user := range users {
                    u[user.ID] = user
                }

                result := make([]*models.User, len(ids))

                for i, id := range ids {
                    result[i] = u[id]
                }

                return result, nil
            },
        }

        ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), userloaderKey, &userloader)

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))
    })
}

func getUserLoader(ctx context.Context) *UserLoader {
    return ctx.Value(userloaderKey).(*UserLoader)
}
```

Comment: You might want to explain what the query is supposed to do, for those who are not familiar with that particular SQL package for go.

Comment: I'm guessing `ids` is a slice of document IDs, and you want to get all users who are in the slice?

Comment: yes that's it, I'm trying to get all users having ids equal to any id in the slice ids

Comment: which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver v1.5.0

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent would be something like this

```
ids := []primitive.ObjectID{ // contains some IDs }
users := client.Database("myDatabase").Collection("users")

cur, err := users.Find(context.TODO(), bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$in": ids}})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
users := client.Database("myDatabase").Collection("users")
cur, err := users.Find(context.TODO(), bson.M{"_id": bson.M{"$in": ids}})
for cur.Next(context.TODO()) {
                    var user *models.User
                    err := cur.Decode(&user)
                    if err != nil {
                        log.Fatal(err)
                    }
                    users = append(users, user)
                }
```

This did the job thank super